# jQuery order for 2 methods to be executed when document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, each

I have this situation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.each(elements,do());
});
```

I would like to execute another new method after the `$.each()` has finished new method called `doOther()`.

Where I can set my new method for example `doOther();` ? I have new `$.each` inside new method just for info.

**Update**

This is my script

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('.countdown'), function() {
        var _element = '.countdown-'+$(this).attr("id");
        if ($(_element).length > 0) {
            var _expDate = $(_element).attr('data-expiration').split(',');
            _expDate.forEach(function(v,i,a){a[i]=parseInt(a[i]);});
            var _datetime = new Date(_expDate[0],_expDate[1],_expDate[2],_expDate[3],_expDate[4],_expDate[5]);
            init_countdown(_element,_datetime);
        }
    });

    $.each($('.countdown'),function() {
        var ips = $(this).text().split(',');
        $(this).html('<div class="span12">'+ips[0]+'</div>');
    }); 
});

function init_countdown(_element,_datetime){
    $(_element).countdown({
        date: _datetime /*"June 7, 2087 15:03:26"*/
    });
}
```

it seems that `$.each($('.countdown')` etc.. is overridden by the first `$.each`, can't understand why.

Comment: you need a third method, and put inside the two you need to execute

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood what you mean, your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.each(elements, do);
    doOther();
});
```

If this isn't what you meant, please edit your original question and add more detail.

Comment: i edited question the fact is it seems override by the first each

Answer (score 1):

This should do it,

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
 $.each(elements,do());
 doOther();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement another method right after your first $.each block

Comment: Infact he needs to call other method after each block.